# Using video.js I am trying to use variables, not text, to supply the video source url and the poster url (and eventually the subtitle (track) element

Tags: javascript, video.js

This is part of the video html I am using....

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster=""  data-setup="{}"> <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
```

...and this is my js to set the video source...

```
var mySource = window.localStorage.getItem("mySource");
document.querySelector("#my-video > source").src = mySource;
```

....which works, after a fashion. It displays two error messages, the second too quick to see, but the first which says "No video with supported format and mime type found" is not ideal. After that, it loads and plays the correct video.

The poster code, which works - it shows the correct poster, is as follows....

```
var myPoster = window.localStorage.getItem("myPoster");
var myPlayer = videojs('my-video'); myPlayer.poster(myPoster);
```

However, including that fragment causes the video not to be found!

Has anyone got a better solution for this problem (ideally to include the subtitle (`<track>`) element as well)?

Answer (score 0):

With Video.js you schould intitialise the player and then use its api to set sources instead of modifying DOM elements directly.

```
var myPlayer = videojs('my-video');
myPlayer.ready(function() {
  myPlayer.poster(myPoster);
  myPlayer.src({
    type: 'video/mp4',
    src: mySource
  });
  myPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack({
    src: myTrack,
    type: 'subtitles',
    language: 'en'
  });
});
```